# HCP Vault - how to access private endpoint?

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault

It might be a silly question. I’ve created Vault cluster in HCP, peered its HVN to AWS VPC, chose not to use public endpoint as this is recommended because of security reasons. But can I access then Vault UI using private URL? Or is it only for CLI type of access? If I can access Vault UI via private endpoint though how this can be done?